# Calculate mean for each row containing lists of values

Tags: pandas, list, rows, mean

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple rows and columns, where each cell contains a list of values. I want to calculate mean of values (in lists) for each row separately.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
l1 = [[1,2,4,3],[1,2,4,3], [1,2,4,3]]
l2 = [[8,2,6,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,4,3]]
l3 = [[1,2,4,9],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,4,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame([l1, l2, l3], columns=list('xyz'))
```

the df:

```
      x          y       z ...
x [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]

y [8,2,6,4] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]

z [1,2,4,9] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]
```

and i want result like this:

```
      x          y       z         MEAN
x [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]   2.50000

y [8,2,6,4] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]   3.33333

z [1,2,4,9] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]   3.00000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the mean 3.333 for the first row - shouldn't it be **(1+2+3+4)*3 / 12** or 2.5

Comment: Another question, how to get lenght of each cell (list) in this dataframe?

Comment: `df['len_x'] = df['x'].apply(len, axis=1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten values per rows by [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to numpy array and call `mean`:

```
df['MEAN'] = [np.concatenate(x).mean() for x in df.to_numpy()]
#for oldier pandas versions
#df['MEAN'] = [np.concatenate(x).mean() for x in df.values]
print (df)
              x             y             z      MEAN
x  [1, 2, 4, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  2.500000
y  [8, 2, 6, 4]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  3.333333
z  [1, 2, 4, 9]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 3]  3.000000
```